# Rails 5 routing and form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to determine the best way to handle form submissions and routing.

I have the *standard _form.html.erb*, as well as *new.html.erb* and *edit.html.erb* - each renders `form`, `subscription = @subscription`, which is declared in the `new` and `edit` controller action.

The model is `subscription`, and this is my `form` element in *_form.html.erb* (it's in the `checkout` namespace) -

```
<%= form_for([:checkout, subscription]) do |f| %>
```

`/checkout/subscriptions/new` is the URL for a new subscription. When you submit the form, it posts to `/subscriptions`.

The problem is that if there are errors, and you refresh the browser (I know users will do this for one reason or another), you get an error message because there is no view for `/subscriptions/index` (I don't need one).

Same applies for editing. If you go to (as an example) `/checkout/subscriptions/14/edit`, everything's great. But if you submit the form, it posts to `/subscriptions` - same problem as with new - if you refresh the page, you get the *no view* error. This is the way Rails handles it with a new scaffold.

So my questions are:

- what's the url I should use in the `form_for` tag?
- what should I do for routing?
- and how can I avoid this error when refreshing the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the rails version of REST works (and should work). The key here is the HTTP method.

Reloading the page creates a `GET` request. While you controller should create resources with `POST` and update with `PATCH/PUT`.

[GET requests should be idempotent](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) (not create, alter or delete resources) so a GET request for `/subscriptions` or `/subscriptions/:id` is very different.

What can you do:

- Use the `window.beforeunload` event in javascript to warn the user that they will lose data.
- Route the `GET /subscriptions` path to `subscriptions#new`.
- Route the `GET /subscriptions/:id` path to `subscriptions#edit`.

Comment: That did it @max - thank you. It never occurred to me to have multiple routes for the same controller action.

Comment: That's a nice explanation. Aprreciate you. Cheers!